# how to add favicon to android home shortcut and mac Capitan Safari

Tags: python, html, flask, favicon

I uses the https://realfavicongenerator.net/ to generate and check the icon, however I tried many times and couldn't get rid of this two following errors:
[image: The Error Image]

The other three are all done and the final code are below, what do I need to change to make it work?

In `home.html`:

```
...some code...
<head>
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
</head>  
...some code...
```

And in my `routes.py`:

```
import os
from flask import send_from_directory

@app.route('/browserconfig.xml')
def browserconfigXml():
  return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'),'browserconfig.xml', mimetype='image/png')

@app.route('/mstile-150x150.png')
def mstilePng():
  return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'),'mstile-150x150.png', mimetype='image/png')
@app.route('/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png')
@app.route('/apple-touch-icon.png')
def androidPng():
  return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'),'apple-touch-icon.png', mimetype='image/png')

@app.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
  return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'),'favicon.ico', mimetype='image/vnd.microsoft.icon')
```

Here are the files in my main/static folder:

```
main.css
android-chrome-192x192.png
android-chrome-512x512.png
apple-touch-ico.png
browserconfig.xml
favicon.ico
favicon-16x16.png
favicon-32x32.png
mstile-150x150.png
site.webmanifest
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: RealFaviconGenerator's author speaking! I realize you found a workaround. Great! Just in case: the error messages from RealFavicon suggest the favicon markups were just not found at all in your homepage. I'm not into Python, but adding the markups in a file named layout.html sounds good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did not really know how I made it work but this what I done: I move the head from home.html to layout.html an also add a few more line:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="/android-chrome-192x192.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

And here is my route.py file:

```
import os
from flask import send_from_directory
@app.route('/browserconfig.xml')
def browserconfigXml():
  return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'),'browserconfig.xml', mimetype='image/png')

@app.route('/mstile-150x150.png')
def mstilePng():
  return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'),'mstile-150x150.png', mimetype='image/png')
@app.route("/favicon-32x32.png")
def andPeng():
  return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'),'favicon-32x32.png', mimetype='image/png')
@app.route('/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png')

@app.route('/android-chrome-192x192.png')
def androidChromePng():
  return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'),'android-chrome-192x192.png', mimetype='image/png')

@app.route('/site.webmanifest')
def siteWebman():
  return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'),'site.webmanifest', mimetype='image/png')

@app.route('/safari-pinned-tab.svg')
def safariPinned():
  return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'),'safari-pinned-tab.svg', mimetype='image/svg')

@app.route('/android-chrome-512x512.png')
def androidChromeFive():
  return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'),'android-chrome-512x512.png', mimetype='image/png')
@app.route('/apple-touch-icon.png')
def applePng():
  return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'),'apple-touch-icon.png', mimetype='image/png')


@app.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
  return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'),'favicon.ico', mimetype='image/vnd.microsoft.icon')
```

I also noticed that I forgot to implement a file in the static folder. So now the static folder looks like this:

```
main.css
android-chrome-192x192.png
android-chrome-512x512.png
apple-touch-ico.png
browserconfig.xml
favicon.ico
favicon-16x16.png
favicon-32x32.png
mstile-150x150.png
site.webmanifest
safari-pinned-tab.svg
```

I'm not sure if this is the best solution but I did know this allows users to see the favicon from android, ios, and windows devices!